How can I determine significant differences within factors and interaction effects?
My study is structured as such (false information, same idea):
Factor A: 3 levels (3 bacterial strains)
Factor B: 3 levels (3 antimicrobials)
Factor C: 2 levels (growth stage of bacteria: early, old)
Factor D: 6 levels (dosage of antimicrobials: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 mg)
measurement of interest: surviving population, $X$
I want to know:

Does factor C significantly impact the measurement of surviving population, $X$,  when accounting for Factor A or factor B?
When comparing the 3 levels of factor A (or factor B), are there significant differences in the surviving population, $X$?

My instinct would be to subset the data and do multiple ANOVAs to compare the effects of Factor A, and Factor B at each dosage (Factor D). And to compare the two treatment levels by doing many many t-tests. But I feel like this is wrong. I just have never worked with a 'complex' (for me) model, and feel lost.
Edit:  So it is a dose response experiment, I suppose I was being too vague. We're measuring log reduction counts (CFU/ml) the two stages of growth (factor C) are 18h exponential and 48h stationary So each strain is subcultured into the two growth groups 18h and 48h at the same time, from the same initial broth culture. Then at the time of exposure, each culture is aliquoted into 7 (control and 6 dosage levels) separate plates, exposed to an antimicrobial, and the cfu counts are measured. We are comparing log reduction values from the control

About factor D: 4 levels seems low, but is this intended to be a typical dose-response curve experiment?

And what are the units of your measurement of interest? Is it supposed to be a percentage?

Some of the details will matter a great deal and you may not have sufficient experience to judge which ones they are. So I would encourage you to describe your experiment and not a made-up example if possible.

You can often answer these kinds of questions by setting up appropriate contrasts. I don't know what software you're working with, but the emmeans package in R is pretty powerful for these kinds of tasks.

@mkt; there are 6 levels, only listed 4. I'll have to fix that.

@mkt
So it is a dose response experiment, I suppose I was being too vague. We're measuring log reduction counts (CFU/ml)
the two stages of growth (factor C) are 18h exponential and 48h stationary
So each strain is subcultured into  the two growth groups 18h and 48h at the same time, from the same initial broth culture. Then at the time of exposure, each culture is aliquoted into 7 (control and 6 dosage levels) separate plates, exposed to an antimicrobial, and the cfu counts are measured. We are comparing log reduction values from the control

Thanks. Please edit these details into the question.

Make sure that you look at the dose-response curves first. That can save a lot of trouble later on.
Your sense is correct that you shouldn't be doing multiple t-tests in a situation like this. There's also no need to do multiple ANOVAs. It's typically best to do a single large model that includes all factors, which you can think of as a multi-way ANOVA or a multiple regression model.
Combining all the data makes the analysis less dependent on the vagaries of sampling and small numbers of observations in each scenario. You take advantage of all the data to get shared estimates of the underlying errors around the model predictions. As @BenBolker noted in a comment, after you build a comprehensive model you can use tools like those in the R emmeans package to make any comparisons that you want, with appropriate correction for multiple comparisons.
You have a few issues to confront, however.
One is that this type of analysis, whether you think of it as a multi-way ANOVA or a multiple regression model, is unlikely to give single answers to either of your (types of) questions. For example, the answer to your first question

does factor C [growth stage] significantly impact the measurement of surviving population, , when accounting for Factor A or factor B?

will probably differ depending on the particular bacterial strain (Factor A) or antimicrobial (Factor B) concentration (Factor D). Similarly, the answer to your second question:

when comparing the 3 levels of factor A (or factor B), are there significant differences in the surviving population, ?

will probably differ depending on the growth stage or antimicrobial concentration (Factor D).
There's nothing wrong with that. Those possibilities are evaluated via the interaction terms of the multiple regression model. It does mean that you have to think carefully about which particular combinations you want to consider.
The second issue is how to deal with the dose-response aspect. In principle, you could treat the 6 drug doses (Factor D) as a 6-level factor variable. That might not be as easy to interpret as some summary measure, like the ED50 (effective dose for 50% survival). The R drc package provides tools for many dose-response models, explained by Ritz et al. in PLoS ONE 10(12): e0146021. You could then use the ED50 values for each situation as input to your model of Factors A, B and C.
The third issue is that, with count data for outcomes, it might not be good to use methods like ANOVA that are designed for continuous outcomes. The variance of count outcomes around their predicted values typically are related to the predicted value (the variance equals the mean in a Poisson model). With large counts and log transformations you might get away with that as an adequate approximation; it depends on details of your experiments. The drc package provides for proper analysis of count data under several different models, if you are using that to summarize your dose-response relationships.
If you are instead modeling all doses as separate levels of a factor, then you could use a corresponding generalized linear model like a Poisson model for the outcomes. Or, as Frank Harrell might suggest, use an ordinal regression model that makes no assumptions about the association between mean values and variance and just works with the ordering of outcome values.
This would be a good opportunity to identify and start working with some experienced local statisticians, who often are available for consultation at academic institutions.
